# ¿Cómo obtener solo los registros de una consulta en un buscador?

Tags: php, mysql

estoy realizando un catalogo de productos en la cual tengo 2 tablas: PRODUCTS, BRANDS.

Esto para mostrar los productos con su respectiva marca.
Bien, ahora tengo un buscador para hacer la consulta:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
INNER JOIN brands
WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR brands.name_brands LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR category LIKE '%".$search."%'
    AND products.name_brands = brands.name_brands
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Al hacer la consulta, me arroja resultados pero con todas las marcas, es decir si necesito buscar (telefono x) me aparece (telefono x con marca 1, telefono x con marca 2, etc hasta la ultima marca).

Que podría estar haciendo mal?

Me podriám ayudar?

Comment: En que tabla almacenas la marca?? En 'BRANDS' ?

Comment: Si, tengo todos los productos **PRODUCTS** (name, brands, image_brands) y las marcas **BRANDS** (name_brands, image_brands)

Comment: cual es el enlace entre ellos? los indices?

Comment: las columnas, PRODUCTS.name_brands y BRANDS.name_brands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba de esta forma:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM products pr
 INNER JOIN brands br ON pr.name_brands = br.name_brands
 WHERE pr.name LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR br.name_brands LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR category LIKE '%".$search."%'
 ORDER BY pr.name ASC
```

Comment: Francisco, muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ha servido de maravilla!!

Comment: Gracias Alan, recuerda votar positiva la respuesta si fue de tu ayuda, un abrazo.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta la condición que vincula las dos tablas en el JOIN. Si no lo pones, estás obteniendo el producto cartesiano (todos por todos), que es lo que te pasa.

Para vincular las tablas, debes igualar la primary key de la tabla "padre" con la foreign key de la tabla hija

Así pues la query quedaría más o menos así (no puedo ponerlo exacto porque desconozco el nombre de las columnas)

```
SELECT *
FROM products
INNER JOIN brands ON products.fk_brand_id = brands.id
WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR brands.name_brands LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR category LIKE '%".$search."%'
    AND products.name_brands = brands.name_brands
ORDER BY name ASC
```